# sed editing multiple lines

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, sh, multiline

Sed editing is always a new challenge to me when it comes to multiple line editing. In this case I have the following pattern:

```
RECORD 4,4 ,5,48 ,7,310 ,10,214608 ,12,199.2 ,13,-19.2 ,15,-83 ,17,35 \
     ,18,0.8 ,21,35 ,22,31.7 ,23,150 ,24,0.8 ,25,150 ,26,0.8 ,28,25 ,29,6 \
     ,30,1200 ,31,1 ,32,0.2 ,33,15 ,36,0.4 ,37,1 ,39,1.1 ,41,4 ,80,2 \
     ,82,1000 ,84,1 ,85,1
```

which I want to convert into:

```
#RECORD 4,4 ,5,48 ,7,310 ,10,214608 ,12,199.2 ,13,-19.2 ,15,-83 ,17,35 \
#   ,18,0.8 ,21,35 ,22,31.7 ,23,150 ,24,0.8 ,25,150 ,26,0.8 ,28,25 ,29,6\
#   ,30,1200 ,31,1 ,32,0.2 ,33,15 ,36,0.4 ,37,1 ,39,1.1 ,41,4 ,80,2 \
#   ,82,1000 ,84,1 ,85,1
```

Besides this I would like to preserve the entirety of these 4 lines (which may be more or less than 4 (unpredictable as the appear in the input) into one (long) line without the backslashes or line wraps.

Two tasks in one so to say.

sed is mandatory.

Comment: I should have mentioned, that the result should look exactly like shown. Not all in one line. The other point was, to write out the pattern space to a file and that as one liners (with the continuation characters '\' and (possibly) space removed. Reason: with a subsequent sed-run all the #-signs should be removed to enable the lines again.

Comment: I should have left out the second task, extracting a one liner, because this was misleading to that I wanted to have the one liner in my edited result. The result should be the same with the original, despite that every line has a # in front of it.

Comment: So...you want one script to comment out the RECORD blocks and another to put them on a single line, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: So to say, yes. If it cannot be done in one pass, like doing in file editing and writing out the one liner to stdout. Other solution would be to run grep over it first - before doing the editing - and collect all the RECORDs.

Comment: It can be done in one pass (I added something about that), but at that point things are becoming a bit ugly. It's the old game of pick your poison. I'd probably use two passes and extract the records once before editing the file in a second pass.

Comment: `sed is mandatory` = `this is homework`, right? Otherwise, clarify why sed is mandatory for you as it's simply the wrong tool for any job involving multiple lines. Also, clarify and show ALL of your expected output and whether it's going to one file or 2.

Comment: Nah, it's not homework. It's ideology :) For one: I do not use perl. I only confine myself to standard unix tools like sh, ed, sed, awk, grep, sort, uniq and all the 'standard utilies' as they existed in the times of 4.2 bsd. And why is sed the wrong tool for multiline editing? You see from the answers that it can very well cope with the task. If you are suggesting awk, well I wouldn't mind either, but to me the sed solution appears simple though when one is used to sed regex and such.

Comment: Regarding my output: every line should be prepended by a #-sign so that the line structure stays intact. There can be a single line with a RECORD in front. Secondly, on a separate output channel, be it stdout, stderr or a separate file I would like to have the pattern in a single line w/o the continuation characters and without the prepended #.

Answer (score 3):

It's not terribly clear how you recognize the blocks you want to comment out, so I'll use blocks from a line that starts with `RECORD` and process as long as there are backslashes at the end (if your requirements differ, the patterns used will need to be amended accordingly).

For that, you could use

```
sed '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g; s/^/#/ }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/^RECORD/ {                            # if you find a line that starts with
                                       # RECORD:
  :a                                   # jump label for looping
  /\\$/ {                              # while there's a backslash at the end
                                       # of the pattern space
    N                                  # fetch the next line
    ba                                 # loop.
  }
                                       # After you got the whole block:
  s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g   # remove backslashes, newlines, spaces
                                       # at the end, beginning of lines
  s/^/#/                               # and put a comment sign at the
                                       # beginning.
}
```

**Addendum:** To keep the line structure intact, instead use

```
sed '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; s/\(^\|\n\)/&#/g }' filename
```

This works pretty much the same way, except the newline-removal is removed, and the comment signs are inserted after every line break (and once at the beginning).

**Addendum 2:** To just put RECORD blocks onto a single line:

```
sed '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g }' filename
```

This is just the first script with the `s/^/#/` bit removed.

**Addendum 3:** To isolate RECORD blocks while putting them onto a single line at the same time,

```
sed -n '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g; p }' filename
```

The `-n` flag suppresses the normal default printing action, and the `p` command replaces it for those lines that we want printed.

To write those records out to a file while commenting them out in the normal output at the same time,

```
sed -e '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; h; s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g; w saved_records.txt' -e 'x; s/\(^\|\n\)/&#/g }' foo.txt
```

There's actually new stuff in this. Shortly annotated:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^RECORD/ {
  :a
  /\\$/ {
    N
    ba
  }
                                      # after assembling the lines
  h                                   # copy them to the hold buffer
  s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g  # put everything on a line
  w saved_records.txt                 # write that to saved_records.txt
  x                                   # swap the original lines back
  s/\(^\|\n\)/&#/g                    # and insert comment signs
}
```

When specifying this code directly on the command line, it is necessary to split it into several `-e` options because the `w` command is not terminated by `;`.

This problem does not arise when putting the code into a file of its own (say `foo.sed`) and running `sed -f foo.sed filename` instead. Or, for the advanced, putting a `#!/bin/sed -f` shebang on top of the file, `chmod +x`ing it and just calling `./foo.sed filename`.

Lastly, to edit the input file in-place and print the records to stdout, this could be amended as follows:

```
sed -i -e '/^RECORD/ { :a /\\$/ { N; ba }; h; s/[[:space:]]*\\\n[[:space:]]*/ /g; w /dev/stdout' -e 'x; s/\(^\|\n\)/&#/g }' filename
```

The new things here are the `-i` flag for inplace editing of the file, and to have `/dev/stdout` as target for the `w` command.

Comment: you got it faster than mine AND with full explain. Could maybe  enhance the first pattern with a `\` check at end of line with `RECORD`

Comment: RECORD is the keyword to recognize the beginning of the pattern. Every line but the last one has the "\" at the end.

Comment: Then this should work exactly as required. @NeronLeVelu I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "check at end of line with RECORD."

Comment: the htlm eat my backslash :-(  i mean `^RECORD.*\\$` as first pattern

Comment: Oh, I see. That depends on whether you want to comment out single-line records as well. I figured it'd make sense to do it, so I put it this way.

Comment: Wintermute, you write: while there's a backslash at the end of the line...  The last line doesn't have a '\' at the end but it should get also a '#' prepended,too.

Comment: And it does. It's fetched before it is checked, and the loop ends only after that.

Comment: Yes, single line RECORDs may appear as well. I hadn't this in mind though at the moment. But you are right, they may occur.

Comment: Thanks, Addendum 1 now works like a charm. And I learnt about sed again.

Comment: Thanks for the extension regarding writing to stdout. I'll implement that too. Everything solved. Great!

Answer (score 2):

```
 sed '/^RECORD.*\\$/,/[^\\]$/ s/^/#/
      s/^RECORD.*/#&/' YourFile
```

After several remark of @Wintermute and more information from OP

Assuming:

- line with `RECORD` at start  are a trigger to modify the next lines
- structure is the same (no line with `\` with a `RECORD` line following directly or empty lines)

Explain:

- take block of line starting with `RECORD` and ending with `\`

  - add `#` in front of each line
- take line (so after ana eventual modification from earlier block that leave only RECORD line without `\` at the end or line without record) and add a `#` at the start if starting with `RECORD`

Comment: I don't think this'll work if there's an empty line after a block, since `[^\\]$` will not match it. Perhaps with `\(^\|[^\\]\)$`?

Comment: tested on my AIX and it works (mainly because i assume that it could not have a line with bad ending line). If it happend, empty line are *commented*, not the worst nor contrary to request but your solution is better in this case

Comment: Yeah, on second thought, that's a bit of a corner case. The `/^RECORD/` check inside surprises me a bit, though; that line should be commented out as well, shouldn't it? I'm thinking `/^RECORD.*\\$/,/\(^\|[^\\]\)$/ s/^/#/`, if we chuck out the "put things on one line" bit.

Comment: with extra explaination this code does not fit anymore, i adapt a bit for inclusionb of any RECORD line *block*

Comment: A pattern range would've been a good trick except for the putting-things-on-one-line part. Still, it'll be useful for someone who comes here in the future with a similar problem, so incremented.